# How to assign a class object to a item in a list? (python)

Tags: python, list, class, sorting

I defined a class with 3 objects inside of it:

```
class abc():
     __slots___ = ('1','2',3')
```

From here, I made a list containing around a thousand elements:

```
lst = [[abc,dfg,9292],[ksdj,lkjsd,9239],...]
```

The third element inside each element is always a number. I want to assign the object called 3 in my class to that third element so that I can sort the list.

To clarify some misconceptions object 3 is actually quantity. Therefore, the third element in each element is considered a quantity.

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: Looks like python to me... @steve correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: What is the object called 3 in your class? You can't have a variable name like that. Can you explain what you mean by "from here, I made a list containing around a thousand elements?" I really don't understand what you've written

Comment: For `__slots__` newbs (like me) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots

Comment: Mr E, I opened a file that contained around 1000 lines. Each line had a element that has 3 elements in it. [abc, dfg, 123]. The 123 is the Quantity that i'm trying to sort.

Comment: @steve Any particular reason you can't just sort the list directly? I'm not following why you're trying to make objects here...

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you're trying to sort the list, create instances of `abc` from elements in your list, or something totally different.

Assuming you wanted to sort your list by the 3rd element of each sublist:

```
lst.sort(key = lambda x: x[2])
```

would sort your list in place.

If you want to create an object of type `abc` from each element in your list, you need to figure out what you're doing with the data from each list element. If you simply want to store it as instance variables, you could do something like this:

```
class ABC():
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

obj_list = [ABC(*x) for x in lst]
```

You could then sort this resulting list of objects if that's what you want.

Comment: The OP may also wish to look at `collections.namedtuple` - but is very unclear what they're after